# jquery appending table with variable strings as ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, apostrophe

I am appending some HTML to an existing table.

as such I am using jquery .append.

this works great. my issue is that I want to post some infotmation to my controller in the form of a variable.

below is my current syntax:

```
 $(tablename).append(
          '<tr>'+   
          '<td><div id="divone" onclick="showdetails('q','+"po"+')">+</div></td>'+
          '</tr>'
 )
```

variable q is a variable with a number. lets say `23`. this renders correctly.
variable po is also a variable but a string, lets say `so149`

when this is appended to the table is appears in HTML as:

```
<tr>
<td>
<div id="divone" onclick="showdetails(23,so149)">+</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

on clicking the div, I get the below error in firebug:

```
ReferenceError: so149is not defined
showdetails(12,so149)
```

because variable po is a string, it sees it as a variable and not a string. how can i get this value to be passed with the post as a string?

I have tried varios apostophe combinations without luck.

Please advise and thanks as always.

Comment: This is one of the reasons to avoid using inline Javascript. Bind the handler with jQuery, and put the parameters in data attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your quotes slightly wrong..

```
'<td><div id="divone" onclick="showdetails('+q+',\''+po+'\')"...
```